# Peer2Peer/ One host - multiple answers?

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming, p2p, peer, video-conferencing

I just managed to create a peer-to-peer connection, sending video from one browser to another. However, I'm wondering if there's any way to do the same but with multiple clients answering and attending the "call" of the host, maybe without even needing to send a video offer. I'm using JavaScript, React and firebase as my signaling system and db.

I have the idea that maybe everytime that someones joins a "call" or "room" It creates another p2p (peerConnection instance) with the ones that are already in the call, however I wouldn't know how to manage the creation of something like that.
I would love some insight about this.